# LyX - Unable to Preview PDF after Upgrade 2.0.6 to 2.1.3

Tags: lyx, pdf

I recently had to upgrade my LyX distribution to remain compatible with a LyX distribution on a different machine.  When I upgraded (2.0.6 to 2.1.3), I was no longer able to generate preview PDFs.  I am still learning the program, and it is not clear to me if I need to redirect the paths for certain actions.  Comparing the preferences across distributions (my old distribution was not overwritten, and I can still push to PDF from it), there does not seem to be a noticeable difference.  On the new distribution, I get the following error in the terminal when I attempt to preview:

```
No protocol specified

** (evince:21375): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Has anyone encountered this before?  The questions that I have seen related to this issue don't seem to match my problem specifically, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:  In response to a comment below, here is quick test of evince.:

```
user:~/dissertation$ evince 02-10-revenueprojections.pdf 
Syntax Warning: parseAction: Unknown annotation action object: URI = 'NULL'
Syntax Warning: parseAction: Unknown annotation action object: URI = 'NULL'

** (evince:22388): WARNING **: Unimplemented annotation: POPPLER_ANNOT_STAMP.  It is a known issue and it might be implemented in the future.
```

Despite the warning, the PDF opens just fine.

Comment: From the error it appears that launching evince is the problem. I'm unclear from your description. Can you open any PDF with evince (e.g. by double clicking on a file in your file manager program such as nautilus)? Have you checked the temporary files directory to see if the PDF is generated correctly?

Comment: Thanks for checking in.  Evince is working just fine it seems. The problem seems isolated to the upgraded version of LyX.  The old version still works, which is why I was wondering about updating of paths.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There is something wrong if `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not set and you are in a GUI environment on a GNU/Linux system set up in a reasonably standard way. Moreover, this is likely to cause other issues, although how serious they are will depend on what exactly is wrong. But this is a symptom, not a cause. (And it has nothing to do with TeX.)

Comment: This is the first time I have had an issue on this front.  I would appreciate if you could elaborate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the best solution in the world, but I just replaced `evince` as the preferred PDF reader.

Tools > Preferences > File Handling > File Formats

I selected the PDF(pdflatex) format, and changed the viewer from `evince` to `xpdf`.